# Phonegap on Multiple Density Devices

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm just starting to learn to develop on Phonegap and I came accross this issue in my first tests.

I made a long list-view with title and description with 100% width and px defined values (for fonts and paddings) on my css.

First, I tested the app on a Motorola Defy+ (mdpi device) and it looked good. After that, I tested the same app on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (xhdpi device) and, obviously, the list-view items got VERY small on the screen:

[image]

This surely is expected, since the interface should fill that many pixels on both devices. But since they have almost the same physical screen size, it would make sense for the interface to have the same size on both. And that's what I want.

I found a lot of people around talking about the "viewport" meta-tag and I decided to give it a go, but no success (tested "width", "initial-scale" and "target-densitydpi").

My question is: is there a way to make the interface behave according to the physical size/screen density (such as dp and sp parameters on Android's native) so those elements have similar real sizes accross all kinds of screen sizes and densities?

Comment: write media query for this

Comment: hmm didn't tought about this, sounds good... only problem though, will I have to create a lot of very specific rules for different sizes and all or is there some known set of queries to target most devices at once?

Answer (score 0):

What about this meta: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`